# Vue js: module store is not defined

Tags: vue.js

in my Vue js project i got the error said `* ./store in ./src/main.js` and i couldn't figure out what is the problem, i use store in my app.vue and it's now working too (`this.$store.dispatch("user", response.data.response);)` it says dispatch is undefined and most probably it's because of store, below is my code please take a look..
can someone please help in this?

```js
//main.js

import Vue from 'vue';
import DashboardPlugin from './plugins/dashboard-plugin';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './routes/router';
import VueSession from 'vue-session'
import store from './store'


export const eventBus = new Vue();
Vue.use(VueSession)

window.token=localStorage.getItem('token');

window.axios=axios
window.axios.defaults.baseURL='http://weblloapi.dev'
window.axios.defaults.params={api_token:window.token}
Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.use(BootstrapVueIcons)
Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.use(DashboardPlugin);

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

//index.js

```js
import BaseCheckbox from './Inputs/BaseCheckbox.vue';
import BaseAlert from './BaseAlert.vue';
import BaseRadio from './Inputs/BaseRadio.vue';
import BaseInput from './Inputs/BaseInput.vue';
import Badge from './Badge';
import BaseProgress from './BaseProgress.vue';
import BaseButton from './BaseButton.vue';

import BaseDropdown from './BaseDropdown.vue';
import BaseTable from './BaseTable.vue';

import Card from './Cards/Card.vue';
import StatsCard from './Cards/StatsCard.vue';
import BaseNav from './Navbar/BaseNav';
import NavbarToggleButton from './Navbar/NavbarToggleButton';

import TabPane from './Tabs/Tab.vue';
import Tabs from './Tabs/Tabs.vue';
import Collapse from './Collapse/Collapse.vue';
import CollapseItem from './Collapse/CollapseItem.vue';
import Modal from './Modal.vue';
import BaseSlider from './BaseSlider.vue';
import LoadingPanel from './LoadingPanel.vue';

import BasePagination from './BasePagination.vue';

import SidebarPlugin from './SidebarPlugin';
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    user:null
  },
  getters: {
    user: state => {
      return state.user;
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    user(state, user) {
      state.user = user;
    }
  },
  actions: {
    user(context, user) {
      context.commit('user', user);
    }
  },

})

export {
  BaseCheckbox,
  Badge,
  BaseAlert,
  BaseProgress,
  BasePagination,
  BaseRadio
};
```

thanks in advance

Comment: what does the error say?

Comment: ccan't find module  ./store in ./src/main.js

Comment: do you have an `index.js` in `./store`?

Comment: If the `index.js` above is the one in `./store` directory, then you shouldn't be importing components in there, importing components should be done in `main.js`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an index.js file inside a directory named store which is in the same location as your main.js

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).